# How to add multiple products to cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, configurable-product

I have a problem in magento 2, I wish to customize the product details page for adding multiple proucts to cart, which means "product-options-wrapper" div along with option to add quantity should be generate dynamically on add new item button click. is it possible using custom module ? I wish to change the view like this

[image]

Comment: I know you asked this 4 years ago, but did you get this to work? And if so do you have any refrences that can point me in the right direction?